# Angular standalone components architecture

Tags: clean-architecture, angular

I am trying to understand the benefits/gains of using standalone components in a real project that my team and myself included are working on, and from my very **humble** point of view, I just can't see much and I would like to hear feedback about it

Without going too much in detail, the current project is using version 13, we are thinking about upgrading to v14 having in mind how we could take advantage of standalone components. We have many feature modules, one shared module, a pipe module, material module and it kind of looks something like this:

```
common
 > material
   > material.module.ts
 > pipes
   > pipe.module.ts
 > shared
   > components
     > input-component
     > button-component
     > autocomplete-component
     > text-area-component
     > dropdown-component
     > and some others...
   > shared.module.ts //the components from above live here
features
 > users
    > components 
    > users.route.module.ts
    > users.module.ts
 > admin
    > components
    > admin.route.module.ts
    > admin.module.ts
 > sales 
    > components
    > sales.route.module.ts
    > sales.module.ts
core
 > components
 > core.route.module.ts // we lazy load the feature modules here
 > core.module.ts
app //root
 > app.component.ts
 > app.route.module.ts // core module is declared here
 > app.module.ts
...(some other folders)
```

Given the new feature of standalone components, I am thinking about making the shared components to be standalone as a first step. So if I do that, each component will be self-contained, it will handle it's own imports and I no longer will require the `shared.module.ts`, so conceptually speaking, I could use my shareable components anywhere without the need of **importing** them on each feature module.

Now, in one of the components from the `user.module.ts`, is using a form with the `reactive forms` approach. Of course, living in this module, I have imported my `shared module` since I am using inputs, dropdowns, buttons, and some others... and here goes the thing I don't see any benefit of standalone components; say I transform my input, dropdown, button components to be standalone, each has `standalone: true`, and the necessary `imports`, now, in order to use them in the form, I have to individually import each of these standalone components to my users module

**user.module.ts**

```js
// BEFORE
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [SharedModule, ...]
})
export class UserAdminModule {}

// AFTER
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [InputComponent, DropdownComponent, ButtonComponent, ...]
})
export class UserAdminModule {}
```

What did I gain with this? Now I have imported 3 "modules" rather than none, and I will require to do the same thing on each of my `feature` modules, and the same could be for `pipes` module if I am using all of them

I was expecting to not require to import on each of my modules, they should be **truly** standalone, you still require to import them... at the end, is the same thing, nothing changed... instead of a single module, now I am importing components...

**before**

[image]

**after**

[image]

I am really curious to hear any useful opinion about this, did I get standalone components wrong? I would appreciate criticism. Thank you in advanced